# WebGL Shader Variables

Tags: opengl-es, shader, webgl

```
var fragmentShaderSource = '\
            varying highp vec4 color; \
            varying mediump vec2 texCoord;\
            varying highp vec3 v; \
            varying highp vec3 n; \
            uniform sampler2D sampler2d;\
            void main(void) \
            { \
                gl_FragColor = color + 0.0 * texture2D(sampler2d, texCoord); \
                gl_FragColor.a = 1.0; \
                console.log(color); \
            } \
    ';
```

I'm new to WebGL, and the strange thing about this is, how is it possible to use variables like **color** or **sampler2d** although I didn't Initialize anything? Is there a default value?

Comment: `varying` parameters have an initial value that is predetermined by interpolating the matching `varying` parameter from the vertex shader. `uniform` parameters are set externally from the shader before it is used for rendering.

Comment: So can we know what the initial value is?

Comment: Initial value is zero meaning texture00. I have posted the answer, read it.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Webgl has a term called texture unit which is integer number. In your code above, you created a sampler and default unit is 0. What does it mean is that the sampler will act on texture associated with TEXTURE00.

If you create a texture object and bind it without making active and with out associating with any texture unit it will be binded as TEXTURE_2D having gl.TEXTURE00 as being active texture.

Suppose you created a trexture object checkerTexture and it is TEXTURE0 which is in ACTIVE_TEXTURE in image and the texture object name ***checkerTexture*** is in top of list. Now in your code if you haven't set uniform value i.e integer, default value is zero. That mean your shader will sample checkerTexture as default.

---

[image]

So if you have multiple texture and you want second texture to be sampled and taken to read the data. If you don't set uniform sampler a texture unit, it will sample TEXTURE00 which mayn't be required case every time.

So with code:

```
   gl.uniform1i(sampler2dLocation, 1);
```

This will let you take second texture object by that sampler.